# Generate automatic project name

Tags: qgis

I want to automatically generate a project name in QGIS. In the best case, the project name consists of the processor and the date of the last processing.

Is there a way to generate this automatically in QGIS, for example via the project variables?

Comment: What do you call "project name" ? is this the QGIS project file name (as in project name.qgz) or the "Project title" from the project properties or a label that you want to generate on canva or layout or ... ?

Comment: Also what is the "last processing" ? the last layout export ? last saving ? last operation on a layer from your project (is so what operation count as processing ?)

Answer (score 4):

I think something like that, if I understood correctly what you want, will save a project with the last processing history entry :

```py
from qgis.gui import QgsGui

# get all processing history
entries = QgsGui.historyProviderRegistry().queryEntries(providerId='processing')
# get last processing entry
entry = entries[-1]

# get the alg name
algorithm_id = entry.entry.get("algorithm_id")
algorithm = QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithmById(algorithm_id) if algorithm_id else None
alg_name = algorithm.displayName() if algorithm else ""
# get the alg date
alg_date = entry.timestamp.toString("yyyy-MM-dd")

# create the project name
project_name = f"{alg_name} {alg_date}"
# print it !
print(project_name)

# or save the project with this new name in "my_path"
# QgsProject.instance().write(f"{my_path}/{project_name}.qgz")
```

Code mainly inspired by the QGIS [processing core plugin code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/python/plugins/processing).